# what is the difference between link_to, redirect_to, and render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am confused about the main difference(s) among `link_to`, `redirect_to` and `render` in Rails. anyone can please explain.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

link_to is used in your view, and generates html code for a link

```
<%= link_to "Google", "http://google.com" %>
```

This will generate in your view the following html

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

redirect_to and render are used in your controller to reply to a request.
redirect_to will simply redirect the request to a new URL, if in your controller you add

```
redirect_to "http://google.com"
```

anyone accessing your page will effectively be redirected to Google

render can be used in many ways, but it's mainly used to render your html views.

```
render "article/show"
```

This will render the view "app/views/article/show.html.erb"

The following link will explain the redirect_to and the render methods more in detail
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Which involve the browser making new requests to the web server?

Answer (score 11):

From the [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

Regarding rendering a view vs redirecting a request

> *. . . render tells Rails which view (or other asset) to use in constructing a response. The redirect_to method does something completely different: it tells the browser to send a new request for a different URL.*

Regarding rendering a view

> *. . . render :action doesn't run any code in the target action . . .*

Regarding redirecting a request

> *. . . Your code stops running and waits for a new request for the browser. It just happens that you've told the browser what request it should make next, by sending back an HTTP 302 status code.*

---

Basically:

**link_to** is a helper method to generate URLs usually used in your views (*.html.erb* files)

**render** tells your controller to render a view without passing any data (say, from a form) to the next controller action.

**redirect_to** does a 302 page redirect, passing data (say, from a form) to either a controller action on your web app, or an external app (ex: google, facebook, a web article you liked, etc)

Answer (score 4):

I actually [just wrote a blog post about this](http://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-08-24-rails-render). The most important bits are copied below (with modifications).

### Controller Methods: `render` vs. `redirect_to`

`render` and `redirect_to` are the two ways that controller actions end (generally speaking). To understand how they work, let's review what controllers do in a Rails app:

- A user tries to access a page.
  (http://localhost:3000/books/index.html)
- Under the hood, the browser sends an HTTP request for the specified path on the server.
  (`GET /books/index.html`)
- The Rails routing system then looks up which controller corresponds to the given request path.
  (`books GET /books/index(.:format)            books#index`)
- The controller prepares some data and then **tells the server what response (*i.e.,* what HTTP header/body content) to send back to the client**.

This last step occurs explicitly when you call `render` or `redirect_to`, or **implicitly if you leave it out**.

That is,

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
end
```

is the same as

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  render :index
end
```

**`render :index`** says, ‘combine the data I've prepared (`@books = Book.all`) with the `books/index.html.erb` view template to generate a complete HTML document, then send that back to the client.’

**`redirect_to @book`** says, ‘tell the client to start the whole process over again, issuing a new `GET` request to `url_for(@book)`.

If you omit both, the action will render a template with the same name as the action itself. In other words, you only need to call `render` explicitly when the view template you want doesn’t match the action you’re rendering it from.

Note that not every controller action has a corresponding view template. Generally, `#create`, `#update`, and `#destroy` (which are all routed to non-`GET` HTTP requests) attempt to make some change to the database and then either `redirect_to` some resource (if it succeeded) or re-`render` the form that preceded it, along with any errors (if it failed).

[As the official guides explain](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) (emphasis mine),

> These two methods [`render` and `redirect_to`] represent the two basic action archetypes used in Action Controllers: **Get-and-show** and **do-and-redirect**. Most actions are variations on these themes.

---

### View Methods: `render` vs. `link_to`

`render` is also used within view templates themselves. Rather than generating a complete HTML document, it's used to insert a **partial view template** into a larger one. Here's the upshot:

- You can create **partial view template** files to be inserted into your standard templates (think of them as modular page components).
- Filenames of partials must begin with an underscore (*e.g.,* `_nav.html.erb`).
- Use `render 'nav'` if you want to include the `_nav.html.erb` partial **from a view located in the same folder**.
- Use `render 'shared/nav'` if you want to include the partial at `app/views/shared/_nav.html.erb` **from any view in your project**.
- Various options and shorthand syntaxes exist for passing data into a partial, rendering multiple partials from a collection object, and more. See [the guides](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) for details.

`link_to` is just a convenience method for inserting anchor tags (`a href` tags) into your view templates. This is useful because a lot of the URLs you'll want to link to are other pages within your application, and those URLs can be referenced using objects or "helper methods", like so:

```
= link_to 'Back', books_path   # renders as <a href="/books">Back</a>
= link_to 'View', @book        # renders as <a href="/book/1">View</a> or similar
```

Answer (score 3):

`link_to` is for use in ERB templates. It outputs a link to a specific path or url.

`redirect_to` is for use in controllers. It causes the client to request the specified path or url once the controller method exits.

`render` is also for use in controllers. It causes Rails to render the specified template.

`redirect_to` and `render` may only be called once in a given controller method.

Answer (score 1):

A `link_to` is used on a form within rails, and is a helper to create a link element within html. The other two are not used in forms, but rather are used in controllers.

You `render` a page if your controller method is linked to that page. E.g. calling 'new' should render the 'new item' page. They fulfil the request that has just been made.

`redirect` is used for exactly that - redirecting. For example, if you try accessing a page where you have to be logged in, you redirect the user to the login page. So,  redirects basically spawn a new request.

Answer (score 1):

link_to will output a standard html anchor=a link [(link_to documentation)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

redirect_to is commonly used for page responses such as update and delete. It will take the parameters you give it and will direct your page appropriately. 
[(redirect_to documentation)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)

render is used for loading partials or loading specific .erb files into others. [(render documentation)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)
There are a bunch of examples on [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) rails guide which should explain render and redirect_to. link_to is pretty different from rendering and redirect_to

Answer (score 1):

A link_to creates a hyperlink to a specific URL, which appears on the HTML.

A redirect_to will decide where to link you to, depending on certain options. For example, if someone is logged on as a user, you might want to show him his settings page, else redirect_to the home page.

A render will open the rendered file, take its content and paste it into the existing file, before sending the whole chunk to the recipient.

Hope I am right.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to):

> As you've seen, render tells Rails which view (or other asset) to use in constructing a response. The redirect_to method does something completely different: it tells the browser to send a new request for a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple explanation [here](https://medium.com/@kerenlerner/render-and-redirect-which-to-use-106ff653ee9a):

> They may seem similar to beginners but they are very different.
> Render tells Rails which view or asset to show a user, without losing access to any variables defined in the controller action.
> Redirect is different. The redirect_to method tells your browser to send a request to another URL.

And basically the same thing in different words from [rails docs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActionView/Rendering_and_Redirecting#:%7E:text=There%20is%20an%20important%20difference,new%20request%20to%20the%20browser.):

> There is an important difference between render and redirect_to: render will tell Rails what view it should use (with the same parameters you may have already sent) but redirect_to sends a new request to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

"redirect_to" will cause the browser to make a new request, whereas "render" renders the specified view for the current request. It is important to use redirect_to after mutating the database or application state. Otherwise, if the user refreshes the page, the browser will make the same request, and the mutation will be repeated.

As for "link_to",  the link_to helper renders a link with its first argument as the link's text and its second argument as the link's destination. If we pass a model object as the second argument, link_to will call the appropriate path helper to convert the object to a path. For example, if we pass an article, link_to will call article_path.