# render gives missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, render

Missing template users/registrations/new with:

```
{ :locale=>[:en], 
  :formats=>[:html], 
  :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]
```

Following

```
redirect_to new_user_registration_url
```

works fine however

```
render new_user_registration_url
```

gives above error.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook

    @user, new_record = User.find_or_create(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?

      if new_record

        sign_in @user

        redirect_to basic_profile_detail_path

      else

        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication 

        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?

      end

    else

      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

      render new_user_registration_url

    end

  end

end
```

Here's my controller however before saving facebook auth data I need to ask for contact number to the user and rest of the form needs to be filled up from @user data. Hence I can't use redirect in this scenario.

Comment: Show your controller code. And, BTW, you misuse `render`, so I would propose some reading, for example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: figured out I need to use render 'devise/registrations/new' as it is inherited from Devise controller.

Answer (score 0):

`Missing template users/registrations/new` means that you have to create a template file under `app/views/users/registrations/` named `new.html`. (see `formats` in the exception).

Nevertheless, as @Marek Lipka said, you misuse render so you should take a look at the following [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time I see this error it's because I should be using

```rb
redirect_to '/some-unique-url-in-my-app`
```

instead of

```rb
render '/some-unique-url-in-my-app`
```

The remaining times it's because there is no `html.erb` file that matches what the app is expecting to find. For example, if you had `render "articles/show"`, then your app would expect to find a file called `app/views/articles/show.html.erb`

There's another good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236319/5783745)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while upgrading an old Rails 2.3 application to Rails 7.

Maybe you only need to remove the extension from the template file.

The old Rails 2.3 code was:

```
render :template => 'companies/list.erb' and return
```

The Rails 7 code that worked for me is:

```
render template: 'companies/list' and return
```