# What methods make new request in rails? When flash is clear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[Action Controller Overview — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)
say

> The flash is a special part of the session which **is cleared with each request**.

When flash is clear? What methods make new request?

I tryed `redirect_to`, `render`, `link_to`.

**redirect_to** -> show then **clear**.
**render** -> show then **not clear**. (So use `flash.now`)
**link_to** -> show then **not clear**.(So use `flash.now`)

So I believe
`redirect_to` make new request.
`redirect_to` is all? other method make new request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**redirect_to**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to) **causes** a new request. It tells the browser to send a new request for a different URL.

**[render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)** can be used in many ways, but it's **mostly** used to render the HTML views to the browser, in other words, it does the heavy lifting of rendering your application's content for use by a browser:

```
render "some_view"
```

in this case there is not HTTP request involved. But, there are other ways that you can use `render`, e.g. rendering an action:

```
render :action_name, notice: "message"
```

in this use case of render there is a HTTP request involved.

**[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)** is a helper method of `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` that is used in your view, and generates HTML code for a given link. It also makes a new HTTP request to your browser in most of the cases. The exception is an Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

**Sessions**

The [`flash`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) is just part of Rails' [session cookie system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions):

> **The flash is a special part of the session** which is cleared with each request

The `session` is a *cookie* stored on the client system.

It is a `hash` (`{key: "value"}`), which means you can store a number of different pieces of data inside it.

---

Rails reserves the `flash` inside the session cookie (it can only be populated through your controllers). You can populate the various elements of the flash session -- it basically looks like this:

```
session: {
   flash: {
      notice: ""
      error: ""
      alert: ""
   }
}
```

This is corroborated [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dd0dc3e7217f8af7877c5831b3d8816d156f21e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L9):

```
@env[Flash::KEY] ||= Flash::FlashHash.from_session_value(session["flash"])
```

---

In its nature, the `session` variable is temporary, as described here:

> Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the **very next action and then cleared out**

This means that each time your application *serves a new request* (IE the user reloads their browser), the flash will be updated.

Remember, *the session is a cookie **stored on the clients' system***. Client systems can *only* be updated through a complete HTTP refresh.

--

To answer your question, *it depends* on how you're using `render`.

If `render` forms part of an HTTP refresh, the flash will be updated. If it is just to add a partial, it won't change the flash.

`redirect_to` is self explanatory. `link_to` invokes a new HTTP request, so the flash will be updated (unless it's bound to ajax).

---

**Render**

In the controller, **render** is often used to describe the "rendering" of a new action:

```
def create
   render :new, notice: "New action"
end
```

Used in this context, the render action will invoke the same process as `redirect_to` -- pushing the browser to load a new url.

Comment: >  it depends on how you're using render.

I see. but How to use(or write) `render` for HTTP refresh.
status option?
[Layouts and Rendering in Rails — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: What do you mean, can you give me a use case?

Comment: I can not understand "If `render` forms part of an HTTP refresh".  Would you give me some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to see examples:

[what is the difference between link_to, redirect_to, and render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236122/what-is-the-difference-between-link-to-redirect-to-and-render)

There is few ways to use in a controller, Example:

```
  def update
    if @contact.update
      flash[:success] = 'The "@contact.title.capitalize" updated Successfully'

      #redirect_to :action => 'index', togo back to contact index page. 
      #redirect_to root_path, togo back to root index page
      redirect_to contact_path #
    else
      # flash pops and renders back to edit page.
      flash[:danger] = "Ouch smth went wrong..."
      render "edit"        
    end
  end
```

Comment: I like to use Danger flashing, cause of bootstrap.


    `<% flash.each do |k,v| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, v, class: "alert alert-#{k} text-center" %>
    <% end %>`